# Check a rotary encoder in python while searching for a socket connection

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi Wi-Fi thermostat in Python 3. It connects to an iPhone app which is working however I need some physical controls on the thermostat. I have managed to get buttons to work but the loop takes 0.5 seconds to complete and therefore the buttons don't work too well. In theory I need to run the socket connection in another thread or put the rotary encoder program into another thread but I then have problems sharing the variables around.

Here is the code for the thermostat so far:

```
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
from RPLCD import CharLCD
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import socket
import os
import time
import threading
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
lcd = CharLCD()

thermometer = (
    0b00100,
    0b01010,
    0b01010,
    0b01110,
    0b01110,
    0b11111,
    0b11111,
    0b01110,
)
lcd.create_char(0, thermometer)

up = (
    0b00100,
    0b01110,
    0b11111,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
)
lcd.create_char(1, up)

down = (
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b00100,
    0b11111,
    0b01110,
    0b00100,
)
lcd.create_char(2, down)

tick = (
    0b00000,
    0b00000,
    0b00001,
    0b00010,
    0b10100,
    0b01000,
    0b00000,
    0b00000,
)
lcd.create_char(3, tick)

global temp
global counter
temp = 9
rounded = 0
counter = 0

def checktemp():
    global rounded
    sensor = W1ThermSensor()
    temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
    rounded = round(temperature)
    return rounded

checktemp()

lcd.clear()
lcd.write_string("Target:  " + str(temp) + "\337C\n\r")
lcd.write_string("Current: " + str(rounded) + "\337C")

while True:
    temp = int(temp)

    if temp > 30:
        temp = 30
    if temp < 5:
        temp = 5

    thread = threading.Thread(target = checktemp)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    if int(temp) > int(rounded):
        GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
        lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(0))
        lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(1))
    elif int(temp) < int(rounded):
        GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
        lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(0))
        lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(2))
    elif int(temp) == int(rounded):
        GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
        lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(0))
        lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
        lcd.write_string(chr(3))
    try:
        HOST = '192.168.1.2'
        PORT = 10000
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(1)
        s.settimeout(0.5)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        #conn.send(str(9).encode())
        conn.send(str(temp).encode())
        while True:
            temp = int(temp)

            if temp > 30:
                temp = 30
            if temp < 5:
                temp = 5
            thread = threading.Thread(target = checktemp)
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
            if int(temp) > int(rounded):
                GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
                lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(0))
                lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(1))
            elif int(temp) < int(rounded):
                GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
                lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(0))
                lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(2))
            elif int(temp) == int(rounded):
                GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
                lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(0))
                lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 15)
                lcd.write_string(chr(3))
            try:
                conn.settimeout(0.5)
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data: break
                data2 = data.decode()
                if int(data2) in range(5, 31):
                    lcd.clear()
                    temp = data2
                    lcd.write_string("Target:  " + str(temp) + "\337C\n\r")
                    lcd.write_string("Current: " + str(rounded) + "\337C")
                else:
                    print("Not in Range!")
            except:
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.write_string("Target:  " + str(temp) + "\337C\n\r")
                lcd.write_string("Current: " + str(rounded) + "\337C")

    except:
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.write_string("Target:  " + str(temp) + "\337C\n\r")
        lcd.write_string("Current: " + str(rounded) + "\337C")
```

And here is what I have for the rotary encoder (A working example from the internet):

```
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep

clk = 15
dt = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(clk, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(dt, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

counter = 0
clkLastState = GPIO.input(clk)

try:

        while True:
                clkState = GPIO.input(clk)
                dtState = GPIO.input(dt)
                if clkState != clkLastState:
                        if dtState != clkState:
                                counter += 0.5
                        else:
                                counter -= 0.5
                        counter = int(counter)
                        print(counter)
                clkLastState = clkState
                sleep(0.001)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change from polling to interupts.

Comment: Hi, How would I go about converting the code to use interrupts? And where abouts would I add in the code for the rotary encoder, it needs to be able to change the variable "temp"

Thanks!

Comment: http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio

Comment: Thank You for your help with this issue, And Thank You for giving me just a link as I learned for the future by working out the solution from the link you provided.

Comment: That's good cause I sure as hell didn't want to write up raspberry pie code here.  (I mostly use arduino and beaglebone) ... but either way interrupts should get closer to real time

Comment: in the future you may also check out the electronics stackexchange.  Most of what you see here is general programming and computer software... not real time embedded systems.